# Javascript - "Compound" Class Inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, visual-studio-code, types, intellisense

Not to be confused with inheriting from multiple classes.

Suppose there's a class, Player, with its own methods and properties:

```
class Player {
//...
}
```

Next, suppose there's a class which extends from Player, with its own special properties

```
class SpecificPlayer extends Player {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.foo = "bar";
  }
}
```

Now suppose there's another class, Core, with a property of type `Player[]` (types are defined through JSDoc-style comments in VSCode), and a method which returns a portion of that array.

```
class Core {
  constructor(players) {
    /** @type {Player[]} */
    this.players = players;
  }

  getSomePlayers() {
    return this.players.filter(...);
  }
}
```

Finally, let there be a class which extends from Core, with a constructor and method as follows:

```
class SpecificClass extends Core {
  /** @param {SpecifcPlayer[]} players */
  constructor(players) {
    super(players);
  }

  doThing() {
    console.log(this.players[0].foo);
    this.getSomePlayers().forEach(p => console.log(p.foo));
  }
}
```

Now, if the following main body code is ran:

```
const SpecificInstance = new SpecificClass([new SpecificPlayer(), new SpecificPlayer()]);
SpecificInstance.doThing();
```

Everything is fine and dandy -- "bar" is printed successfully for all log statements.

However, when writing the code (specifically the body of `doThing`), VSCode Intellisense would only recognize `this.players` as a type of `Player`, meaning it wouldn't recognize the property `foo`. How would I go about writing the classes such that the VSCode autocomplete/Intellisense recognizes the correct type of `this.players`, and each method in `Core` which uses `this.players` also returns the correct type of `SpecificPlayer`? Realistically, there are several classes extending from Core, some with their own special variation on Player. As such, the types returned should be that which was provided originally to the constructor.

(Or is there a better way to organize/format my code?)